# Post message on facebook via android app

Tags: android, android-facebook

What are the essential parameters (APP ID, Token, etc.) that need to be taken from developers.facebook.com in order to just post a message to facebook wall from an android application?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16970648/1919641) shows ways to log in and [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16971078/1919641) one how to post message after login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you Need the Facebook SDK for this [FB SDK](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk). There are many tutorials, please use the search function.

Comment: Thanks Oli. I have dwnldd the FB SDK and imported the same in my project. I have also created a App on FB and set the App ID in my code. My question is are there any other parameters that I need to set apart from the APP Id in my code or on FB dev page?

Comment: You could check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/) worked for me :)

Comment: I think apart from APP ID and HASHKEY there are no other parameters we need to set in code. Let me know if my assumption is correct.