# Creating a class for Facebook SDK 3.0 on Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

Is it possible to create a class to encapsulate the Android SDK on android?

i.e - I don't want to clutter my activity with all the FB sessions and stuff, I want to have a class that I can call and it will do the job.

For example,

```
FacebookSDK sdk = new FacebookSDK();
sdk.publish();
```

For now I couldn't find a way to do this, without using Fragments or cluttering my activity with the facebook code.

Many Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.

Your activity needs to be notifying the Facebook SDK of lifecycle events in order to properly store state and handle the UI flow to and from the Facebook SDK activities.

[UILifecycleHelper](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/UiLifecycleHelper) is an effort to encapsulate this as much as possible.

You may be able to unclutter your code by having all your activities extend some base class (i.e. FBActivity) that makes all the proper calls to `UILifecycleHelper`, though this only helps if all your activities are interacting with Facebook in a fairly uniform manner.

Answer (score 2):

Its all about session management.

```
//Check for active session -
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

// if it doesnt exist create one-
if(session ==null)
session= new Session(getApplicationContext) 

// if it is not open open it first

    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
        .setPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info"))
        .setCallback(statusCallback));
    }
    else
    {
        Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), this, true, statusCallback);
    }

    // callback listner fires when session state changes
    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            //If your session is opened
            if(session.isOpened()
              publishData(session);
        }
```

Method to publish your request -

```
    public void publishData(Session session)
    {
     OpenRequest open = new OpenRequest(this);
            open.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
            open.setPermissions(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"email", "publish_actions", "user_birthday", "user_hometown"}));
            open.setCallback(this);
                    session.openForPublish(open);
    }
```

publishData defination can also be -

```
public void publishData(Session session)
        {
Bundle params = new Bundle();

params.putByteArray("message", "some message".egtBytes());
params.putByteArray("name", "some name".getBytes());
params.putByteArray("link", "some link".getBytes());
params.putByteArray("description", "Some description".getBytes());
params.putByteArray("picture", "picture.url".getBytes());

Request postToWall = Request.newRestRequest(session, 
                                                    "/" + pickedUsersId.get(0) + "/feed", params, HttpMethod.POST);
postToWall.setCallback( new Request.Callback() 
{

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) 
    {
         // get response
        Log.e(TAG, response.toString());

    }
});
Request.executeBatchAsync(postToWall);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that you will still need an activity for all of that

Comment: no you can just pass listner inside the method and you will get call inside your class there is no need for activity if you know what I mean or if you want I can add code segment for that too