# Invalid App Id:facebook app Id

Tags: java, android, facebook, share

I have been trying to create an application in android for sharing my content with facebook.but whenever I try to login facebook through the login button in my application....It shows me **Invalid App Id:facebook app Id**.I goggled a lot for these and found this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/ to register our application in facebook,before we run it on the emulator.Even after following the above link and registering my application in facebook,am getting the same error..plz help me..

Comment: can you please paste your code here?

Comment: Yeah...heres the link...I'm using the whole same code......http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2012/05/share-text-to-facebook-twitter-android.html#comment-form and for the code https://github.com/dhaval0122/Share_to_Facebook_twitter

Comment: Did you set application access Key and id correctly??

Comment: Why don't you use the sample code provided by Facebook. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/scrumptious/

Comment: did you set you app id in the "strings.xml" file. You must add the app id received from facebook to your project.

Comment: @Tarun yES..STILL not working....

Comment: Check [this](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application/) out.

Comment: @ArshadParwez yeah...I have done that...

Comment: Then add your logcat here

Comment: Code is important. We can't guess what you have implemented and whats missing.

Comment: @ArshadParwez.Could you plz post the code...then?If u have done..

Comment: @Mihir still getiing the error in your sample example......FATAL EXCEPTION java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.Facebook

Comment: which sdk you are using, if you are using 3.0 or above, `com.facebook.android.Facebook` is deprecated.

Comment: @Mihir im using 4.2.....Which SDK should i use....specifically..

Comment: @Mihir....Sorry..Im using 2.1 SDK.....

Comment: Download the [Latest SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-android-sdk-current.zip) and then check this [tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16971078/2405196).

Comment: @Mihir Still not working...

Comment: Have you generated correct hash from the keystore file.

Comment: @Mihir yes.....I have generated and have even put it on the facebook developers site

Comment: Can you put your code on GIT or somewhere so I can have a look at it.

Comment: @Kiran: You can use this link to download a sample app for using Facebook SDK3.0 : https://code.google.com/p/list-high-light/downloads/list?can=1&q=