# Facebook Sdk 3.0 doesnt open dialog like facebook sdk 2.0

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

In facebook sdk 2.0 devices that dont have facebook app installed the below code opens a web dialog.

```
mFacebook.authorize(myActivity.this, new String[] {AppConstants.FACEBOOK_PERMISSION,AppConstants.EMAIL_PERMISSION,AppConstants.VIDEO_PERMISSION},Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new LoginDialogListener());
```

But in sdk 3.0, working on emulator that doesnt have native facebook app, my facebook session code is not working

```
Session.openActiveSession(MainActivity.this, true, callback);
OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(this); 
openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
openRequest.setCallback(null);
List<String> PERMISSIONS = new ArrayList<String>();
PERMISSIONS.add("email");
_session.openForRead(openRequest);
```

Though it is working on devices that have facebook preinstalled.

Comment: openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);?

Comment: what about that...I already have that in my code.

Comment: remove it! you dont need it.

Comment: still nothing hapening

Comment: implement [webdialog](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16970648/1919641).