# Facebook login button only asks public permissions

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am implementing facebook sdk in my Android app and i am setting my login button to ask for specific permissions like this:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, container, false);

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);


    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_location", "user_friends", "user_photos"));

    return view;
}
```

however, facebook only asks for permissions on public info, i need to logout and log in again for it to ask me for the rest of the permissions, how can i get ot to ask all the permissions at once?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about this, but the documentation mentions that `setReadPermissions` only works before an open session. Otherwise, `clearPermissions` must be called before setting the new read/publish permissions.

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.5/class/LoginButton/#setReadPermissions

Does that help? Could it be that you already have an open session?

Comment: so where can i put this so that it will be called before the session is opned this is the splash screen...

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Android, but are you sure you don't make calls such as `Session.openActiveSession` before this? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948180/login-approach-with-android-facebook-3-0-sdk

Answer (score 0):

If you've already made permission and later modified, you can remove the app here

https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

And login again.